# How to access local css class names from within the angular component

Tags: css, angular

I need to access the generated css classname from within an angular component, in order to style a 3rd-party component.

Angular does some magic transformations on the local css classnames to enable scoping. I need to apply some custom styles to an [ngx-datatable](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/) component. To do this, I need to pass it custom classnames. Because of what angular does to the classnames, these no longer match.

Adding the classnames to the global scope or using `::ng-deep` both work, however I would rather not break the encapsulation.

*dashboard-component.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent {
    getRowClass(row){
        return 'my-class';
    }
}
```

*dashboard-component.scss*

```css
.my-class {
   background: green;
}
```

*dashboard-component.html*

```html
<ngx-datatable
   [rowclass]="getRowClass"
></ngx-datatable>
```

The way I see it I should be able to access some reference to the css class from within the component, say `this._styles`, which will then carry the generated name of the class at runtime, so I can do

```js
getRowClass(row){
    return this._styles['my-class'];
}
```

Comment: you can just set the `encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not able to propagate your styles to `ngx-datatable`.

You can use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` within your `@component` but make sure you use it carefully as it will lead to some weird css behaviours.

Next, What you can do is create a container for your dashboard.html file like:

```
<div class="dashboard-container">
  <ngx-datatable></ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

and inside your `dashboard.scss` you can reference the parent container

```
.dashboard-container {
  .my-style{}
}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of creating the container?

Comment: if you don't set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` this style will not work 

Comment: @A.Bertrand just create a wrapper  for the classes so will not effect other componenet use the same class

Comment: can be a good wrapper is like this  `ngx-datatable { .my-style {} }` 

Comment: cI have use it here  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-responsive-demo-v2apo5?file=app%2Fdemo-component.scss

Comment: @Alok the wrapper class will be a problem solver good job for this and I have use the component tag name instead so any class apply somewhere else will not affected 

Comment: Right that makes sense, yeah. It's far from pretty but it seems this is the closest you can get without breaking encapsulation

Answer (score 1):

Just put the css classes in the global style file ,otherwise you will need to use `::ng-deep`,so my advice to put ngx-datatable in the global style file

check the ngx-datatable [demo](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/tree/master/demo) `asset/app.css` where the did the same

another option you can set the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` on the component the the class name will be the same

```
    @Component({
      selector: "app-demo",
      templateUrl: "./demo.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./demo.component.scss"],
      encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
   export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
```

*demo.component.scss*

```
ngx-datatable {
  .green-color {
    background:green;

    & div {
      color :#fff;
    }
  }
}
```

> set the encapsulation to none or put the style in global style file are the same here because both ways will be the style globally without any change

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-responsive-demo-v2apo5)